# Send matrix to python function from matlab

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matlab code that is going to use a PSO algorithm that is constructed in python, that as several parameters, knowing that one of those parameters is a 10x5 matrix, and is always giving me an error when i try to run the matlab code, so i put the code and the error that occurs next:

PS: I already tested the pso algorithm in python with same matrix, but when i use it in matlab, it doesn't work.

MATLAB code:

```
s = size(CurrentPop, 1);
velocity_matrix = [];
NewPop = [];

for gen = 1:gen_max
    
    NewPop, velocity_matrix = py.pso_algorithm.pso(n_chr, n_par, CurrentPop, velocity_matrix, gen);
    CurrentPop = EvaluateFirestation(NewPop, n_par, fuelmodels);
```

The error that appears that always occurs in the following line of the python function `particles = particles_array[:, :n_par]`:

> Error using pso_algorithm>pso (line 46)
> Python Error: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method
> Python function 'pso' might not be able to accept at least one input argument at position 3. The function may require a specific data type that you can construct from the MATLAB array. For more information, see the documentation for Python function 'pso' and working with Python arrays.

Python function:

```
def pso(population, n_par, current_pop, velocity_matrix, generation):
    # Initialization
    # Population
    particles_array = np.array(current_pop)
    particles = particles_array[:, :n_par]
    # Particle's best position
    pbest_position = particles
    # Fitness
    # ULTIMA COLUNA DE CURRENT_POP
    pbest_fitness = particles_array[:, n_par]
    # Index of the best particle
    gbest_index = np.argmin(pbest_fitness)  # VAI BUSCAR O INDICE DO MENOR VALOR EM PBEST_FITNESS
    # Global best particle position
    gbest_position = pbest_position[gbest_index]
    # Velocity (starting from 0 speed)
    if generation == 1:
        velocity = [[0.0 for j in range(n_par)] for i in range(population)]
    else:
        velocity = velocity_matrix

    for n in range(population):
        # Update the velocity of each particle
        velocity[n] = update_velocity(particles[n], velocity[n], pbest_position[n], gbest_position, n_par)
        # Move the particles to new position
        particles[n] = update_position(particles[n], velocity[n])

    particles = np.insert(particles, n_par, pbest_fitness, axis=1)
    velocity = np.array(velocity)
    # print(particles)
    # print(velocity)

    return particles, velocity
```

Comment: MATLAB does not create NumPy arrays (don’t ask why, I don’t get this at all). I think it’s a list of lists that you get as input to your Python function. So you need to cast the data to an array, or change your indexing.

Comment: Thanks, i have done what you said but now it gives me another error. `Python Error: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method` on the line of the python code that i mentioned above, any idea?

Comment: Check the types of your input parameters, then read the MATLAB docs for how to force values to be passed as specific Python types, or convert them to the right types within your Python code. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-python.html —— Note that in MATLAB all values are `double` by default, so `n_par` is likely a Python `float`.